# Download large file from google drive link

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I've been trying to install this "drive.google.com/file/d/1ApVcJISPovYuWEidnkkTJi_NI8sD1Xmx" zip file into my own drive using google colab, but I can't seem to make it work.

I think it has to do with the size of it, but so far I've tried both

```
!gdown 1ApVcJISPovYuWEidnkkTJi_NI8sD1Xmx
```

as well as

```
!wget drive.google.com/file/d/1ApVcJISPovYuWEidnkkTJi_NI8sD1Xmx
```

but no matter what I try I get an error, either saying too many people have downloaded for !gdown, or http error using !wget.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Try this, `!wget --no-check-certificate 'https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1ApVcJISPovYuWEidnkkTJi_NI8sD1Xmx' -O output.zip`

Comment: Sadly it only seems to install a file that's not 2ko, when it's supposed to be 13GO.

Answer (score 0):

First run this to connect and mount your google drive acount:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
```

You should receive:

> Mounted at /content/gdrive

Then u need to use :

```
!unzip -u 'zip file source address' -d 'zip file destination address'
```

This will work for your case :

```
!unzip -u '/content/gdrive/MyDrive/file/d/1ApVcJISPovYuWEidnkkTJi_NI8sD1Xmx.zip' -d '/content/gdrive/MyDrive/ZippedFileLocation/'
```

Comment: First, thank you. And second, i'm getting an error after playing the code:
unzip:  cannot find or open /content/gdrive/MyDrive/file/d/1ApVcJISPovYuWEidnkkTJi_NI8sD1Xmx.zip, /content/gdrive/MyDrive/file/d/1ApVcJISPovYuWEidnkkTJi_NI8sD1Xmx.zip.zip or /content/gdrive/MyDrive/file/d/1ApVcJISPovYuWEidnkkTJi_NI8sD1Xmx.zip.ZIP
I don't have the file yet. My issue lies in getting the file in the drive.

Comment: Do you want to get the zipped file from the internet? Or you already have zipped file in your pc, and u want to upload it into your google drive?

Comment: I'm trying to get a file from a public link that isn't mine.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you mount your google drive.

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

Then you should use the following command.

```
!wget -O /content/drive/MyDrive/filename.zip "https://public-link.com/file.zip"
```